# How to control when pdf page open,Esc button action?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

When I am Open pdf preview then after Esc button click that pdf file is closing.I want to controle that esc button using AngularJS.Am using below code for converting webpage to pdf preview.

```
 $scope.printExternoData = function() {
        var printContents = angular.element('#myModalHistExterna').html();

        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        frame1.css({ "position": "absolute", "top": "-1000000px" });
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title><link href="css/histintpdf.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(printContents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 5000);
    };
```

Comment: "When I am Open pdf preview" — How are you doing this? Are you using a library? Are you using a frame? Are you just linking to it and letting the browser handle it?

Comment: am using Iframe